# How to display the results of inner join query table in sqlite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

So, I'm using C# winrt with SQLite database. I want to display the results of the query which i have "join"ed.

I have 2 tables which are Student and Course.

Student has : id(PK), name, courseid

Course has : courseid(PK), coursename

And here is my code :

```
        var query1 = conn.QueryAsync<Student>("select * from Student s inner Join Course c on s.courseid  = c.courseid");
        var query2 = conn.QueryAsync<Course>("select * from Course c inner join Student s on c.courseid = s.courseid");
        var result1 = await query1;
        var result2 = await query2;
        lstJoin.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in result1)
        {
            string text = "Name: " + item.name + ", Course Id: " + item.courseid + ", Course Name : " + item.coursename;
            lstJoin.Items.Add(text);
        }
```

But the "item.coursename" is error, so i can't display it. And then, if I change result1 in foreach with result 2, "item.name" will be error. What should I do so I can display both of them? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it in classic way? like SQLiteCommand object with command text:

```
    strCommandText = "SELECT tbl1.*,tbl2.* FROM Table1 tbl1 INNER JOIN Table2 tbl2 ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID";
```

Or is it a specification that you need to use it this way??
Because I had the same issue when I was using the SQLite Helper file.